# Price slider bug on prestashop layered navigation module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In layered navigation block module of a Prestashop 1.6 store I have activated the price filter option and configured it to show prices with tax.
However, on the frontend the filter are using prices without tax, which results in showing products outside of the price range selected by user.
How can I fix that?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Can you check this thread and tell me if it is the same problem, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300072/layered-navigation-wrong-prices-and-range