# Layered navigation wrong prices and range

Tags: filter, prestashop-1.6, layered-navigation

I am using Presta 1.6 and the blocklayered module to filter products by price value. However, the filters show wrong prices and range.
What do I mean:

When the range is between 5,95 and 6,25 I get products that are 5.40, 5,50 and even 4.90.

[image]

I have tried to set the filtering options with and without tax but nothing changes. 
The prices that are shown are nowhere close to the "no tax price" of the products.

The range of the filter is also wrong the $min-price and $max-price are close but not exact.

The shop's currency is BGN - Bulgarian Lev.

Anyone tackled this problem?

Comment: Did you go to layered navigation module config and rebuild price index?

Comment: Yes I did. Also I reseted the module, with no success.